# Facing NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@38054ba0 is closed

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jruby, jndi, sequel

My code is written in jRuby and I deployed in Tomcat using Warbler. I am using Sequel to query the MySQL database. I am using two layers of database connection pooling. One is native Sequel pooling another is JNDI pooling at the Tomcat level. The connection string is:

```
DB = Sequel.connect("jdbc:jndi:java:comp/env/test", :logger => $db_log, :max_connections => 10)
```

This connection string is defined in app.rb which gets loaded only when there is a fresh deployment or Tomcat is restarted. This creates a Sequel connection pool and all the threads share this pool. 
The JNDI config in my `$CATALINA_OME/conf/context.xml` is:

```
<Resource
name="test"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="10"
maxIdle="5"
maxWait="9000"
username="test_db"
password="test_db"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
testOnBorrow="true"
testWhileIdle="true"
validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnReturn="true"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
removeAbandoned="true"
logAbandoned="true"
url="jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/test"
/>
```

I am using `DB.disconnect` to return connections to the JNDI pool to ensure that no thread uses a connection that's previously been used. I am doing this to ensure the `wait_timeout` error. `auto_reconnect=true` doesn't seem to solve the `wait_timeout` problem properly.
Everything was working fine until a few days back when I started to get errors like:

```
W, [2012-07-26T05:10:30.999000 #29456]  WARN -- : 134325951259087 == NativeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
D, [2012-07-26T05:10:31.001000 #29456] DEBUG -- : 134325951259087 == ["sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor23:-1:in `newInstance'", "sun/reflect/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27:in `newInstance'", "java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java:513:in `newInstance'", "com/mysql/jdbc/Util.java:409:in `handleNewInstance'", "com/mysql/jdbc/SQLError.java:1118:in `createCommunicationsException'", "com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java:343:in `<init>'", "com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java:2308:in `connectOneTryOnly'", "com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java:2122:in `createNewIO'", "com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java:774:in `<init>'", "com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC4Connection.java:49:in `<init>'", "sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25:-1:in `newInstance'", "sun/reflect/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27:in `newInstance'", "java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java:513:in `newInstance'", "com/mysql/jdbc/Util.java:409:in `handleNewInstance'"
```

and

```
W, [2012-07-26T10:19:14.029000 #1572]  WARN -- : 134327815053548 == NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@5a0655d is closed.
D, [2012-07-26T10:19:14.030000 #1572] DEBUG -- : 134327815053548 == ["org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp/DelegatingConnection.java:398:in `checkOpen'", "org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp/DelegatingConnection.java:255:in `createStatement'", "file:/usr/local/tomcat-instance/test/webapps/service/WEB-INF/lib/santa-gems.jar!/gems/sequel-3.34.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:523:in `statement'", "file:/usr/local/tomcat-instance/test/webapps/service/WEB-INF/lib/santa-gems.jar!/gems/sequel-3.34.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:233:in `execute'", "file:/usr/local/tomcat-instance/test/webapps/service/WEB-INF/lib/santa-gems.jar!/gems/sequel-3.34.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:88:in `hold'", "file:/usr/local/tomcat-instance/test/webapps/service/WEB-INF/lib/santa-gems.jar!/gems/sequel-3.34.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:234:in `synchronize'", "file:/usr/local/tomcat-instance/testv/webapps/service/WEB-INF/lib/santa-gems.jar!/gems/sequel-3.34.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:232:in `execute'", "file:/usr/local/tomcat-instance/test/webapps/service/WEB-INF/lib/santa-gems.jar!/gems/sequel-3.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:744:in `execute'", "file:/usr/local/tomcat-instance/test/webapps/service/WEB-INF/l
```

These errors are occurring too frequently to be ignored.

The only change that has happened  is the database host, but I have made sure that the timeout variables remained the same. The values are:

```
interactive_timeout=300
connect_timeout=300
wait_timeout=10
```

Is there anything else that could create the difference?

Answer (score 0):

"Communications Link Failure" usually means that that your program can't connect to the database *at all*. Typical problems are incorrect hostname and port number (which are easy to double-check) or the existence of one or more firewalls, both software and hardware, in between your program and your database.

It's best (if you can) to use the command-line `mysql` utility to verify that you can connect from the machine running your application to the database server. If that works, then you need to check your `<Resource>` configuration. If it doesn't work, then you will need to look into the existence of a firewall.

Note that most recent versions of Microsoft Windows (for example) come with their firewall enabled by default which might not allow your program to make an external connection over an unrecognized port (3306). So, check your local (i.e. on the machine running the webapp) firewall configuration first, then talk to your network administrator to see if there are other firewalls in the way if things don't work.